# Should we ask about why we should kill someone who committed Zina?

Tags: sharia, zina

Salam,

In Sharia, Should we kill the person who did Zina ?

Should we understand that someone who did Zina is someone who can never be a good person in the future if we let it live ? this is why we need to kill this person ?

Thank you,

Comment: I guess this question needs some more input: Are you asking why we should punish a person who commits zina -having doubts whether it is allowed to ask or correct-? Not all would be condemned to death! Or are you asking whether the death sentence means that in Islam we don't expect good from this person. Maybe you should also consider asking separate questions.

Comment: Yes @Medi1Saif I agree, my question looks composed of two questions (because two interrogation points) But in fact I am asking if in Islam condamnation means that this person who did Zina (or something punished by death) = this person can never be a good person again, and this is why we death is the punishment ?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question? I do have a strong guess that this isn't the reason or at least not the main reason, but Allah knows best!

Answer (score 1):

You should know that Islam rules were made in favor of the Muslims not vice versa, and the main purpose in Islam not to punish, but to show truth, and if there is a way to help the sinner person, Islam will help him/her.

For a person to be considered in **ZINA** he/she must be witnessed by 4 persons who have certain descriptions with the right to testify in a court and in-front of a judge, and they must see him doing **ZINA** in action with their eyes, and then the 4 will testify one after the other in-front of the judge, and if one didn't show up or say something different than the other, their testify will be considered ill, and the accused person will be free. **As you see** it is not that easy to prove someone guilty, and only the Judge has the right to decide, not anyone else.

However, in order to prevent people from underestimating **ZINA**, this punishment was chosen, and it is stoning not just killing, because stoning is very painful, hence a painful punishment for a very great sin.

The final answer, NO, it is because Islam want to keep the nature that ALLAH created us upon as it is, and prevent all the problems that comes out of ZINA, and family issues,  **HONORING THE WOMAN** from being a commodity, also because ALLAH gave us a **HALAL** way and called it **MARRIAGE**, and lastly because ALLAH said so, and He is not to be questioned, but we are.

Answer (score 0):

The threshold for adultery must be established, and the threshold for adultery for a married man is stoning to death. The threshold for adultery must be established on a married adulterer.

the adultery(man or woman) may born a girl that will be married to (his-her) son and creat a family is forbidden ,

wish you found it well